# Error when running tensorflow install package

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, data-mining

I'm trying to install tensorflow and i don't know how to fix this error:

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-intel, tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\OneDrive - Universidad Católica de Chile\\PUC\\7°Semestre\\Mineria\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\llvm-project\\mlir\\_virtual_includes\\BufferizableOpInterfaceIncGen\\mlir\\Dialect\\Bufferization\\IR\\BufferizableOpInterface.cpp.inc'
```

I changed pyvenv.cfg:

`include-system-site-packages = true`

Comment: pip install "tensorflow<2.11" try this, documentations says the following => "# Anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native"

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering an OS Error because the path you have specified exceeds the maximum character limit of 260 characters.
It can be overcome with the following steps :

1. Hit the Start button and type 'regedit' to open the Registry Editor.
2. In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following path :

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
> ```

3. On the right, find the value named **LongPathsEnabled** and double click on it.
   If you don't find it, create it by right-clicking the FileSystem key, choosing New > DWORD (32-bit) Value, and then naming the new value LongPathsEnabled.
4. In the value’s properties window, change the value from 0 to 1 in the “Value data” box and then click OK.
5. Close the RegEdit

For more information, please view this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters).

Be informed that Windows is compatible only with TensorFlow versions <=2.10.
Refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for information regarding TensorFlow compatibility.